# Coffee and Water ratio Calculator

Tags: javascript, math

I have different Coffee:Water ratios like 1:13, 1:14, 1:15, 1:16, 1:17. I have 2 inputs for water one for amount and for units(liter, milliters, grams etc.) and 2 inputs for Ground coffee and 2 for brewed coffee.

Below here just an example and I value changes it changes the values for others as well. I am having of figuring out the formula. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Ratio (Coffee : Water)
1:16

Water
80

Milliliters

Ground Coffee
5

Grams

Brewed Coffee
70

Milliliters

```js
if (document.activeElement.id === 'waterAmount' || document.activeElement.id === 'waterUnit') {
  // If waterAmount or waterUnit is changed, update coffeeAmount and brewedCoffeeAmount
  coffeeAmount = (waterAmount / selectedRatio).toFixed(2);
  brewedCoffeeAmount = (waterAmount + coffeeAmount).toFixed(2);
} else if (document.activeElement.id === 'coffeeAmount' || document.activeElement.id === 'coffeeUnit') {
  // If coffeeAmount or coffeeUnit is changed, update waterAmount and brewedCoffeeAmount
  waterAmount = (coffeeAmount / selectedRatio).toFixed(2);
  brewedCoffeeAmount = (coffeeAmount * selectedRatio).toFixed(2);
  // alert(brewedCoffeeAmount)
} else if (document.activeElement.id === 'brewedcoffeeAmount' || document.activeElement.id === 'brewedCoffeeUnit') {
  // If brewedCoffeeAmount or brewedCoffeeUnit is changed, update waterAmount and coffeeAmount
  coffeeAmount = (brewedCoffeeAmount / selectedRatio).toFixed(2);
  waterAmount = (coffeeAmount * selectedRatio).toFixed(2);
}
```

This is my current formula but I am getting wrong values

Comment: If this is a Math formula problem, then the question does not belong to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Can you please confirm if this is something that has to do with the wrong formula being used or a problem with implementing it in JavaScript?

Comment: for 1:16 (the example you posted) you have 80ml of water and 70ml of brewed coffee; in your formula the result should be `waterAmount + coffeeAmount` but how can it be less than the water amount?

Comment: I mean, if water is 80, coffee is 1/16th of that, which is 5. how could the result be 70? it can be 85 or 75, if you add or subtract coffe from water (not sure how that works in actualuty), but 70? how?

Comment: Please update your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78119699/coffeewater-ratio-calculation) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: yeah, also considering the other question includes the "unit to grams" schema, while this does not